# Mcrypt not recognized

Tags: install, mcrypt

I have nginx and PHP up and running.  `phpinfo()` shows that mcrypt is installed and enabled.  I was sure to `sudo php5enmod mcrypt`.  However, Craft is still complaining the mcrypt isn't installed.  What else can I troubleshoot?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it wasn’t an issue to begin with, as shown by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  Must have been caching or something.  I'm up and running.  Computer voodoo.